# How to use Git within MIT-Scheme's Edwin?

Tags: git, mit-scheme, edwin

There's support for Git under Edwin, the emacs-clone that comes with MIT-Scheme: I find some code for it in the source-tree. However, I don't get it to work: I can't find the correct commands that do the job.

So the question is: how to use Git within MIT-Scheme's Edwin? I should be able to "git status", "git diff", "git commit" and so on from within Edwin...

I want to stick with Edwin, so please no suggestions like "switch to GNU Emacs and run MIT-Scheme from within GNU Emacs".

Tnx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading the source-code I found that versioning under Edwin is modeled after versioning in Emacs (of course!); more specifically it's adapted from "vc.el". Information about that is easy to find, obviously...

See [the relevant documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/index.html) under "Version Control".